# String split by backslash does not split

Tags: javascript, string, split

When i split a string by backslash, it is not really splitting. Rather it seems to be removing the backslash

I tried different combinations. But none seems to be working as i expected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display the array values after the split.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var str = "How\are you doing today?";
  var res = str.split("\\");
  console.log('res is', res);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

i expect the variable res to an array with 2 values, first one be 'How' and second one be 'are you doing today?'. But the res is an array of 1 value of 'Howare you doing today?'

Comment: i was actually trying to find file name from a path. initially i was using below code
`
  var str = "C:\Naresh\Desktop\1.txt";
  console.log(str);

  var n = str.lastIndexOf("\\");
  console.log('n is', n);
`

but n is printed as -1

Comment: That is because `str` doesn't contain any ```\``` characters because the one in the string literal is not escaped.

Answer (score 0):

As the backslash is an unescaped escape character, you won't find it in the original string, so `split()` won't find nothing to split, thus returning the *original string*.

```js
var str = "How\are you doing today?"; // backslash is an escape character...
console.log("My string: ", str); // So you won't find it in the string
var res = str.split("\\");
console.log('My String again: ', res[0]); // That's because you get back the original string
```

Comment: got it. so first i need to replace \ by \\ and then do anything else like split or lastIndexOf. Thanks.

Comment: 1 question. 

var str = 'C:\Naresh\Desktop\1.txt'; 
console.log('str is', str);

It prints str is C:NareshDesktop.txt in chrome developer tools console logs. There is a box shown after Desktop. when i copy paste it here, it is not getting printed.

You can see if u run above 2 lines in chrome developer tools. I am not able to figure out why it is coming like that. Also i am not able to replace \ with \\ using command str.replace("\\", "\\\\");

My input is coming as 'C:\Naresh\Desktop\1.txt' but i am not able to pull file name from it due to these issues.